# How to print contents of a URL in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: web-scraping, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

What do I need to do to print the content of that URL address?

```
https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmZW9yEfDjNb9tJ9pCBDzbHc7Q1EXXexqcyjvQtZ2HQC4q/1568.json
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use well know [`requests`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#quickstart) library.

```
conda install requests
```

You need to make a request via `requests.get()` and then get JSON data via an available method that `requests` library offer [`requests.get().json()`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content).

Then you need to grab the data by the `key` (*you can just print out the response and see what the output is for a better understanding*) as you would get values from the dictionary.

---

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/How-to-print-contents-of-a-URL-in-Jupyter-Notebook#main.py) (*this code snippet will work in the notebook as well*):

```py
import requests

response = requests.get('https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmZW9yEfDjNb9tJ9pCBDzbHc7Q1EXXexqcyjvQtZ2HQC4q/1568.json').json()

print(response)
print(response['description'])

# output:
'''
{'dna': '1f4465815267fbf10e37602b8250901655207607', 'name': '#1568', 'description': 'A one of a kind Goon from the Cryptoon world - a collection of 6,969 unique generative NFTs', 'image': 'ipfs://QmbVQN7Tbva94HaBSm8WQVWjKT4CsNsWJ3Dd66y4ew179b/1568.png', 'edition': 1568, 'date': 1634177317007, 'attributes': [{'trait_type': 'background', 'value': 'green'}, {'trait_type': 'shoes', 'value': 'socks'}, {'trait_type': 'hands', 'value': 'flame_sword'}, {'trait_type': 'shorts', 'value': 'grey'}, {'trait_type': 'body', 'value': 'scaley'}, {'trait_type': 'accessory', 'value': 'wu'}, {'trait_type': 'head', 'value': 'long_horns'}, {'trait_type': 'eyes', 'value': 'glasses_white_eyebrows'}, {'trait_type': 'mouth', 'value': 'smiling_mouse'}], 'compiler': 'HashLips Art Engine'}
A one of a kind Goon from the Cryptoon world - a collection of 6,969 unique generative NFTs

'''
```